# How to replace a character with replace function in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to replace the character `{` and `}` in a html string to `{{` and `}}` i am using the replace function but i have the following error :

```
$scope.selectedtemplate.template.replace  is not a  function
```

My code

```
 $scope.selectedtemplate.template = $scope.selectedtemplate.template.replace("{" , "{{" ) ;
 $scope.selectedtemplate.template = $scope.selectedtemplate.template.replace("}" , "}}" ) ;
```

`template` is the HTML string

Comment: Apparently it's *not* an HTML string, as otherwise it would have a `.replace` method. Make sure the property really contains the value you expect at that time.

Comment: should have `null` check first and then do `.replace` string.

Comment: No isn't null was an object , i converted the object to string but  don't replace  the character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with yore code:

- you need to convert template to a string before manipulating it as a string
- you should replace the character globaly:

  ```
  $scope.selectedtemplate.template = $scope.selectedtemplate.template.toString().replace(/{/g , "{{" ) ;
  $scope.selectedtemplate.template = $scope.selectedtemplate.template.toString().replace(/}/g , "}}" ) ;
  ```

Comment: what if template is `null/undefined`?

Comment: the code above should apparently be wrapped with a if

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/33tom882/2/

You are probably getting the "*replace is not a function*" error because **$scope.selectedtemplate.template** is undefined or is *not* type of string. See here for more info on the string.replace function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

It seems like there would be a better way to solve your actual issue though, which would be to use Angular $scope properties to manage your variables rather than directly modifying the HTML as a string.